# Uninstall Adobe Acrobat from Safe Mode Command prompt line

Tags: uninstall

need help uninstalling Adobe acrobat reader from Safe mode command prompt as my computer keep refreshing Desktop and task bar and in even Safe mode, can only work in Command prompt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type `cmd`, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to open Windows CMD prompt as Administrator.
- Get the *full* application description:

> wmic product get description | findstr "adobe"

- Then plug the *correct* description (there may be multiple Adobe products, into the following:

> wmic product where "description='*full application name*' " uninstall

Comment: Cannot get to Windows refreshing reloading but unable to click on anything( no desktop icon either) I even tried in Safe Mode to get to CMD same problem reloading windows, I can get to in to Safe Mode or boot mode command prompt and need to know how uninstall Adobe acrobat in boot mode

Comment: Can you or can you *not* get to command prompt? Try online translation if English is difficult.

Comment: I cannot get to command  prompt in normal Or Safe Mode as it keep on refreshing screen it closes anything I try to open so quickly. I tried trouble shooting using Windows 10 Advance option and selecting Command line option C:\ and need to know how to uninstall Adobe as I read Adobe could be causing this problem

Comment: Try downloading the OS as ISO from Microsoft and perform reinstall, keeping files, if nothing else works.